# Setting up android app from PC to phone

Tags: android, html

I have build a app in my pc which I want to test in my phone but I have no idea how to send it to phone as app , please let me know the process I'm new to this.

Comment: The [Using Hardware Devices](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) document in the Android development documentation will help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your device with PC using USB Cable and send your application to the Device. For this you require the driver for your device. You need to search for your suitable driver, install them and then you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

just copy that app to memory card and run it in your phone.
If you develop that app with eclipse you also can run in eclipse over adb connect (google search)

Answer (score 0):

It should be automatic when you connect your device and run the app.

You have to setup your device for USB debugging. It should give you an option once you connect it to the PC. Mount as media device or USB debugging.

Here is a video tutorial. http://youtu.be/AkWdpdO7p-4

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you have a routed device, it's even easier to do with via wi-fi with the app like [wifi Adb](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb) or similar.

Answer (score 0):

- Install ADB Driver of Device in PC.
- On USB debugging in Device from settings.
- Plug-in your Device.
- Run your App.

Answer (score 0):

- Turn on `USB DEBUGGING` on your device.
- Connect your phone with desktop/laptop via USB
- Run your app, at this moment a dialog will appear and you have to choose connected device, choose device and run.
- If it don't show log, then go to `DDMS` and select your device.